# allow xframe in windows server

Tags: windows, x-frame-options

Firefox updated and now my site doesn't show the embedded iframe form. My site is hosted on a Windows server. I am trying to allow a Google form. I've got
`<configuration> <system.webServer> <httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM https://docs.google.com" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol> </system.webServer> </configuration>`

in the web.config page but it's still giving me an error. How do I allow iframes on my site so that Firefox will display? No issues with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM has very limited support: https://caniuse.com/?search=allow-from

You should use Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors in addition. Browsers that understand this will ignore X-Frame-Options, while IE11 which doesn't understand Content-Security-Policy will keep using X-Frame-Options. This way you'll have all relevant browsers covered.

You will need to add this custom header

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors https://docs.google.com;">
```