AWS Cloudfront: Set `X-Frame-Options` to something other than `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN`
According to AWS docs, in cloudfront, the valid properties for X-Frame-Options:

DENY
SAMEORIGIN

What if we want to embed this page in a different origin, such as
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM foobar

Without introducing a lambda just for this?
Potential dupe without a certain answer.

This answer is likely more relevant on headers than the dupe article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653758/allow-xframe-in-windows-server/64711750#64711750
